# How to chain commands in Ant?

Tags: maven, ant, maven-antrun-plugin

How can I chain commands using maven ant-run-plugin? I want something simillar to this unix command chain:

```
find . | grep .xml | myCommand
```

Comment: Why would you like to do such things in a Maven build? What would you like to achieve?

Comment: This is more a question about Apache Ant then about Maven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept in Ant which is the closer to pipelining in unix command line is [FilterChains](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html).